# why does vs change all the project guids after adding ARM template project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-rm-template

**What am I doing wrong? Why is my solution changing all the project GUIDs when I add a new ARM template project?**

I add an existing project to my solution:

[image]

And I choose my Azure Resource Group deployment project:

[image]

**Why is it changing all the project GUIDs?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> why does vs change all the project guids after adding ARM template project?

It happens to occasionally **when we have the same project in multiple solutions**, each solution uses a different GUID for that project, and updates the project accordingly.

The solution is to manually modify the .sln files to get them in sync.

To solve the problem, select a single GUID for your shared project; Make sure all the solutions that open it have that single thus the same GUID in their solution files. (Please backup your files before making these changes)

You could check the credit for this thread:

[Can't Avoid the ProjectGuid from Being Changed in .csproj File](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d632940-cc1d-49d5-a64c-d3e999216cbd/cant-avoid-the-projectguid-from-being-changed-in-csproj-file?forum=csharpide)

> That’s caused by multiple solutions has different references to the
> shared project, so whenever you save a solution that opens a project,
> the solution apply it's own reference (GUID) to the project
> file(.csproj).

Comment: can you please help with my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69037021/how-to-set-a-connection-string-for-web-app-in-arm-template-that-references-a-key